# Is mute (Fn + F8) button on a HP laptop a physical switch

Tags: windows-10, security, microphone, privacy

My laptop has a physical mute button (F8).

- Is this a physical switch or a software switch?
- I am trying to understand if malware could disable the mute button or not

Thanks

Comment: It is physical. However the keyboard tells Windows that it is physically F8 or Mute based on the Fn key. Keys cost money.

Comment: However is the actual disabling of the mic done by a physical switch or software flag when F8 is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Software muted. It muted by Windows. Keyboard electronics send mute key to Windows, Windows does what needs to be done. These types of keys are known as AppKeys.

> **Keyboard Keys for Browsing and Other Functions**
>
> Microsoft Windows provides support for keyboards with special keys for
> browser functions, media functions, application launching, and power
> management. The WM_APPCOMMAND supports the extra keyboard keys. In
> addition, the ShellProc function is modified to support the extra
> keyboard keys.
>
> It is unlikely that a child window in a component application will be
> able to directly implement commands for these extra keyboard keys. So
> when one of these keys is pressed, DefWindowProc will send a
> WM_APPCOMMAND message to a window. DefWindowProc will also bubble the
> WM_APPCOMMAND message to its parent window. This is similar to the way
> context menus are invoked with the right mouse button, which is that
> DefWindowProc sends a WM_CONTEXTMENU message on a right button click,
> and bubbles it to its parent. Additionally, if DefWindowProc receives
> a WM_APPCOMMAND message for a top-level window, it will call a shell
> hook with code HSHELL_APPCOMMAND.
>
> Windows also supports the Microsoft IntelliMouse Explorer, which is a
> mouse with five buttons. The two extra buttons support forward and
> backward browser navigation. For more information, see XBUTTONs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input

So the program with focus gets the key, it is likely not programmed to handle it (unless it directly applies eg Media Player). Programs call DefWindowProc for all commands they don't handle (or should). DefWindowProc will turn it into a WM_AppCommand (as other keys/menus get turned into WM_Command). If the program call DefWindowProc with this Windows will notify any program that has asked to be notified. If nothing else wants to mute it then Windows will.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Could malware then turn the mute off without me realizing? An orange light comes on when I press F8 to mute and I was trying to understand if malware could unmute. Thanks

Comment: Any program can mute / unmute.

Comment: Programs arguing over the mute is more likely than malware. Try a clean boot. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and on the Options menu tick Hide Windows Entries. Untick what is left. Keep a note of what you are doing. Also run it as admin.

Comment: Thanks for writing in so much detail. This was more of a hypothetical question to see how reliable the mute button is. Based on what you said, it sounds like some other program could unmute without me realizing it.

Comment: That is true for Windows applications. However UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps that run on Windows, XBox, or Phones you need to give the app permission in Settings.